# Search data from JSON string stored in DB

Tags: sql, json, jpql

I have a `{"Name":[{"value":"First Name"}],"City":[{"value":"Delhi"},{"value":"London"]}` varchar value stored in a column of db. I need to search every Person having city Delhi using JPQL. Is it good to store JSON string in db?

Comment: it's better to stick in column (seperate it as column of a row) if you want to use that index or column in searching

Comment: what is your db versiyon ?

Comment: I can not separate it as it needs a lot of design change. DB is HSQL 2.3

Comment: then in that case maybe a wildcard search will solve that

Comment: Could you please explain how as i am new to this technology.

Answer (score 0):

Well, substring matching can work for you in the most of the cases, but it's not precise and will be slow.

You can try something like that:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("SELECT table FROM Table table ");
sb.append("WHERE table.columnWithJson like '%\"City\":[%:city%]}' ");

Query q = em.createQuery(sb.toString())
q.setParameter("city", ""Delhi);
```

If you are using some database with support for regular expression and don't mind to abandon JPQL and use native query, this is an alternative for you too.